# Unable to @Override the compareTo() method in Java

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm writing a `BankAccount` class that puts a bunch of bank accounts into an array list and sorts them according to their account number. I wrote the `compareTo()` method as follows:

```
public int compareTo(BankAccount another){
    if (Integer.parseInt(this.getAccountNumber()) > Integer.parseInt(another.getAccountNumber()))
        return 1;
    else if(Integer.parseInt(this.getAccountNumber()) < Integer.parseInt(another.getAccountNumber()))
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
```

In my main method, `accounts` is the variable for the array list. When I try to do `Collections.sort(accounts);` it is unable to do it. It gives me an error saying something like "cannot instantiate from arguments because actual and formal arguments differ in length" and "inferred type does not conform to declared bound(s)". I thought this was due to my not overriding the `compareTo()` method but when I try to `@Override it`, it says "method does not override or implement a method from a supertype". I don't understand what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `BankAccount` class *declare* that it implements `Comparable<BankAccount>`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your `BankAccount` class should implement the [`java.lang.Comparable<BankAccount>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, it appears this is not the case in your code. Indeed, [`Collection.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) is taking a collection of `Comparable<T>` as an argument.

Comment: And it must implement Comparable<BankAccount>, not just Comparable.

Comment: @user949300 I had realized that and edited before you submitted your comment :)

Comment: Thanks. This was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that your class declaration looks like this:

```
public class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount>
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to Override the `compareTo` method your class has to implement the `Comparable` interface. `compareTo` is not, by default, part of `java.lang.Object`.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you forgot to have your class implement Comparable. Make sure your class declaration looks like this:

`... class BankAccount ... implements Comparable<BankAccount>`

Comment: @DylanBroussard On a related note, using `@Override` only has the effect that the compiler checks whether a method actually overrides something from a superclass or implements an interface method. It doesn't have any other functional result. The entire intention of that annotation is exactly catching the sort of error you ran into.

Answer (score 1):

Does your class implement the Comparable interface? If yes can you check the import to make sure it is the default (java.lang.Comparable) instead of from some other package